# How to convert an ArrayList of hashmap$entry to hashmap

Tags: java, groovy

I originally started with a normal LinkedHashMap

`def person = [fname: "John", sname: "Wood", age: 23, job: "developer"]`

Then I sliced this map like this `def personChanged = person.entrySet().toList()[(1..-1)]` which returns an ArrayList of LinkedHashMap$Entries.

Now I am struggling to convert this Arraylist `personChanged` to its original type (LinkedHashMap). something like `def personChanged = [sname: "Wood", age: 23, job: "developer"]`.

I hope I make sense, please HELP me, anyone.

Thanks

Comment: something like this should work `personChanged.collectEntries{e-> [e.key, e.value] }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
def personChanged = [:]
person.entrySet().toList()[1..-1].each { personChanged[it.key] = it.value }
```